# What does the first line in the "docker-compose.yml" file, that specifies the version mean?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, version

In the first line of the `docker-compose.yml` file we specify a version:

```
version: '3.9'
```

**What exactly does this mean?!**

After installing the latest version, I tried the following in my Windows 10 `cmd`:

```
docker-compose --version
```

and the output was:

```
Docker Compose version v2.17.2
```

so how is it that we type `3.9` in the first line?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That specific line means you are using the new plugin version of Compose that ignores the `version:` line.

There are two different implementations of the Compose tool, one written in Python (`docker-compose` with a hyphen) and one written in Go and distributed as a Docker extension (`docker compose` with a space).  Your output `Docker Compose version v2...` means you are using the newer Go-plugin version of Compose.

Separately, there are four different versions of the Compose file format:

| Version | `version:` | Supports | Python Compose | Plugin Compose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Absent | Pre-Docker networks | Y |  |
| [2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) | `2`, through `2.4` | Single-host Docker | Y | Y |
| [3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) | `3`, through `3.8` | Docker Swarm | Y | Y |
| [Specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) | Ignored | Plugin Compose only |  | Y |

In particular, see [Compose file versions and upgrading](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/): there was never a `version: '3.9'`, which means the Python version of Compose will reject the file.  The plugin version of Compose uses the Compose Specification format, which is mostly backwards-compatible with both the version 2 and 3 formats.

Versions 2 and 3 have some minor differences especially around resource constraints, where version 2 generally directly mirrors `docker run` options and version 3 has some options that are compatible with Swarm but are ignored if you aren't using it.

My personal practice has generally been to use `version: '3.8'`, which is the most recent version of the file format that both Compose implementations support.  If I need the resource constraints then I'll use `version: '2.4'` instead (I do not use Swarm).  If I was going to write something that used a Compose Specification specific feature then I'd probably write `version: '4'` to indicate the difference; my experience elsewhere has been that these kinds of version markers tend to be useful.

As of this writing in May 2023, Docker is planning to desupport the Python version of Compose by the end of June 2023, which will reduce the number of options in this matrix.  In particular, this will mean the `version:` line is ignored always, and any file will be interpreted as per the Compose Specification and not one of the older file formats.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! for the time and the detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/04-version-and-name/

> Top-level version property is defined by the specification for backward compatibility but is only informative.

It specifies the version of the compose file schema, not the version of docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

Top-level **version property** is defined by the specification for backward compatibility but is only informative (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/04-version-and-name/)

Backward compatibility can be used to preserve older software that would have otherwise been lost when a manufacturer decides to stop supporting older hardware (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

Is the version of docker composer yalm file format.
Every version depend on a Docker Engine version and it can add new parameters or new variables.

Here you can see how it changes: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).